# i want to store a video link in object array as service and i want to data bind it in another page

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework

service page contains array of object

```
{
         course_id:3,
        course_name:'Angular',
        course_intro:'AngularJS is a JavaScript framework. It can be added to an HTML page with a <script> tag.AngularJS extends HTML attributes with Directives, and binds data to HTML with Expressions.',
        course_link: 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/nmFaZ6dVkt4'
   },
```

html page here data binding of course_link did not work properly.

```
<ion-list>
        <div class="card">
            <ion-item>
 <div class="video-container">
                   <iframe ng-src="{{co.course_link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                </div>
            </ion-item>
        </div>
</ion-list>
```

this is the error i got

```
`ionic.bundle.js:26794 Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: {{co.course_link}}
Error: [$sce:insecurl] Blocked loading resource from url not allowed by $sceDelegate policy.  URL: https://www.youtube.com/embed/nmFaZ6dVkt4
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$sce/insecurl?p0=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fembed%2FnmFaZ6dVkt4
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7Bco.course_li…ecurl%3Fp0%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.youtube.com%252Fembed%252FnmFaZ6dVkt4
    at ionic.bundle.js:13438
    at Function.$interpolateMinErr.interr (ionic.bundle.js:25073)
    at parseStringifyInterceptor (ionic.bundle.js:25403)
    at Array.regularInterceptedExpression (ionic.bundle.js:28789)
    at interpolationFn (ionic.bundle.js:25373)
    at attrInterpolatePreLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:22884)
    at invokeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:22993)
    at nodeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:22371)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21703)
    at compositeLinkFn (ionic.bundle.js:21706)`
```

Comment: please help me@anybody

Comment: please help me@you

Comment: no body here to answer me?